# MKMapView rotation iOS6 scaling

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, ios6, ios6-maps

Before iOS6 I used to rotate the MKMapView based on the user's GPS-direction (NOT HEADING), using a subview of the MKMapView. It all worked perfectly, I initialized the view as follows:

```
mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] init];    
mapView.delegate = self;
mapView.clipsToBounds = FALSE;
mapView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;        
self.view = mapView;
```

And when rotating I did the following:

```
UIView *innerMap = [mapView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
if([innerMap isKindOfClass:[UIView class]])
{
    innerMap.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(-lastDegrees));
}
```

As I said, all worked perfectly. The nice thing was then when the map rotated, it automatically scaled to the entire frame of the view and filled the black corners that the rotation created.

However, the new iOS6 Maps does not scale and fill the corners! So when it rotates, half of the view is missing and the other half is black (background-color).
What have I tried?

- Trying all different subviews of the new MKMapview (also set their resizingmask to the same value as the mapview)
- Tried to set the contentmode to scaleToFill (also in the subviews)
- Tried to set the autoresizes subviews to true
- Tried to reset the frame after rotating

Unfortunately, all my attempts have no effect at all. Somehow the GoogleMaps scaled and filled the black corners automatically and the iOS Maps do not. So am I missing something here, some awesome property of UIView that I'm forgetting or is this simply not possible with the new iOS6 Maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about making the MapView much larger than the screen size so when it rotates you can't seen around it?

Comment: Hi, thanks, it's a valid solution and I've already implemented this in the current version. The problem is however that I don't like this solution as the user needs to load more data than necessary and on 3G the iPhone4 takes too much time to load the Maps. I was just wondering whether I missed something on auto-resizing.

Comment: I use the method described by Craig. No one has complained yet about data usage. Tens of thousands sold. You can size your mapView just right so that it isn't too too big. Also the way I do it is I have a regular view that I size in the XIB the way I want it, then in code I create a MapView, size it, and add as a subView to the XIB view.